# If $f ◦f$ is differentiable, then $f ◦f ◦f$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus

Let $ f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$.

If f ◦ f is differentiable, then $f ◦ f ◦ f$ is differentiable?

how can I prove this? it feels like true by the chain rule .. but it feels also it is not always possible, there's have to be maybe a counterexample..

Comment: The chain rule works only is the function is differentiable, $(g(f(x)))'\ne g'(f(x))f'(x)$ if $g(f(x))$ is not differentiable, this is why your argument is wrong

Answer (score 4):

Take $f(x)=\frac 1 x, x \ne 0$ and $f(x) = 0, x = 0$ as a counterexample

Comment: can you please explain a little more detail ? tnx

Comment: @It-maril. The function defined by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac 1 x & (x \neq 0) \\
0 & (x = 0)
\end{cases}$$
is not continuous at $x=0$ and therefore not differentiable there. It fulfills $f \circ f = \mathrm{id},$ i.e. $f(f(x)) = x,$ so $f \circ f$ is differentiable. But $f \circ f \circ f = f$ is not differentiable. This therefore provides a counterexample.

Comment: now i see it..thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} +x & x \in \mathbb{Q},\\ -x & x \not\in\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$, then $f\circ f(x) = x$ is differentiable everywhere. However $f\circ f\circ f = f$ is not continuous and hence not differentiable for any non-zero $x$.